# Alexander polynomial and orientation

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

This should be a simple question, but for some reason I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. My question is: is the Alexander polynomial defined as an invariant of oriented knots or of unoriented knots? That is to say, is the Alexander polynomial of a knot always equal to the Alexander polynomial of its inverse?

Comment: The Alexander polynomial is a knot invariant of oriented knots.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you!! I heard somewhere that the Alexander polynomial separates links of braid index 3. Is this true for *oriented* links of braid index 3 as well?

Comment: No, the braid-index-3 link L5a1 is not isotopic to itself when one component has reversed orientation, and they both have the same Alexander polynomials.

Comment: @KyleMiller thanks so much for the answer! Two (hopefully) quick questions: (1) so just confirming that it is true that the Alexander polynomial separates unoriented links of braid index 3? (2) does the link L5a1 goes to when reversing orientation also have braid index 3?

Comment: It looks like (1) is not true, L5a1 and L7n2 appear to have the same Alexander polynomials no matter the orientations and both have braid index 3. (2) I did not check myself, but LinkInfo says so. [LinkInfo query](https://linkinfo.sitehost.iu.edu/results.php?searchmode=selectknot&desktopmode=0&mobilemode=0&singleknotprev=&submittype=selectknot&category%5B%5D=le6&category%5B%5D=eq7&name=%3D1&braid_index=%3D1&multivariable_alexander=%3D1&startrow=0&rows=44). Note that this is showing multivariable Alexander polynomials, which are slightly different.

Comment: I used [KnotFolio](https://kmill.github.io/knotfolio/) to calculate their single-variable Alexander polynomials, and both L5a1 and L7n2 have $-t^3+3t^2-3t+1$.

Comment: @KyleMiller Ah, okay, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an invariant of oriented links -- the construction of the infinite cyclic cover depends on the orientation of each component, and different choices can in principle give you different coverings.

For 1-component links, the orientation does not matter. Change in orientation corresponds to substituting $t^{-1}$ for $t$ in the polynomial, and the Alexander polynomial is symmetric (modulo the group of units for $\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}]$).

However, for multi-component links the orientation does matter. The following link is L9n4{1} according to LinkInfo, and its Alexander polynomial is $-t^5+t^4-t+1$. If you reverse the orientation of the small loop, you get L9n4{0}, which has Alexander polynomial $-t^7+t^6-t+1$.

[image]